# Performance of Parallel Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm trying to modify the sequential "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm in order to take advantage of multiple cores. My goal was to increase performance relative to the vanilla algorithm, but all of my attempts have been futile...

Here's what I have thus far:

```
public class ParallelSieve implements SieveCalculator
{
    private int nThreads;

    public ParallelSieve(int nThreads) {
        this.nThreads = nThreads;
    }

    @Override
    public SieveResult calculate(int ceiling) {
        if (ceiling < Primes.MIN) {
            return SieveResult.emptyResult();
        }

        ThreadSafeBitSet isComposite = new ThreadSafeBitSet(ceiling + 1);

        ForkJoinPool threadPool = new ForkJoinPool(nThreads);

        for (int n = Primes.MIN; n * n <= ceiling; ++n) {
            if (isComposite.get(n)) {
                continue;
            }
            int from = n * n;
            int to = (ceiling / n) * n;
            threadPool.invoke(new RecursivelyMarkSieve(isComposite, from, to, n));
        }

        threadPool.shutdown();

        return new SieveResult(isComposite);
    }

    private class RecursivelyMarkSieve extends RecursiveAction
    {
        private static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;
        private final ThreadSafeBitSet isComposite;
        private final int from, to, step;

        RecursivelyMarkSieve(ThreadSafeBitSet isComposite, int from, int to, int step) {
            this.isComposite = isComposite;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.step = step;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            int workload = (to - from) / step + 1;
            if (workload <= THRESHOLD) {
                for (int index = from; index <= to; index += step) {
                    isComposite.set(index);
                }
                return;
            }

            int middle = (to - from) / (2 * step);
            int leftSplit = from + middle * step;
            int rightSplit = from + (middle + 1) * step;
            ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(
                    new RecursivelyMarkSieve(isComposite, from, leftSplit, step),
                    new RecursivelyMarkSieve(isComposite, rightSplit, to, step)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My thought process was, once a prime value is found, we can break up the work of marking its multiples via a thread pool. I was drawn to the ForkJoinPool because I can limit the number of threads being used, and easily submit it custom, recursive tasks that break up the work of marking multiples. Still, my solution is too slow! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With all prospective multi-threading solutions you have to balance the advantage to be gained by multiplying the amount of processing available against the overheads of administering the multi-threaded solution.

In particular:

- There is some overhead to starting threads.
- If you synchronize or use a thread-safe class (which has synchronization built in) there is the overhead of synchronization, plus the fact that while using synchronized methods you are possibly funnelling the solution back down to a single thread.

Looking at your solution, the actual logic (the compute method) has very little in it in terms of computation, but accesses the thread-safe bit set and it starts a new thread. So the overheads will far outweight the actual logic.

To use multi-threading effectively you need to figure out how to split up your task such that there is a significant amount of work to be done by each thread and the use of an synchronized data structures is limited. You can't invoke a new thread for each integer you come across.

There is a lot online on how to parallelize the sieve of Eratosthenes, so I suggest looking at how others have tackled the problem.

The general paradigm today is "map-reduce". Split the problem-set into chunks. Process each chunk separately. Collate the results back together again. Repeat and/or recurse.